# How can I differentiate query parameters in routing paths in React-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is the my route code:

```
<Switch>{createRoutes()}</Switch>

const createRoutes = () =>
  Routes.map(({ component: Component, urls }) =>
    urls.map((url) => (
      <Route
        path={url}
        exact
        render={() => <Component/>}
      />
    )),
  );
  
const Routes = [
  {
    urls: ['/'],
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    urls: ['/test'],
    component: Test,
  },
];
```

And what I want is, when url is '/test?x=1' match component **Test**, and when url is '/test' will match component **Home**.
How can I be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react-router-dom` only considers the path part of the URL for route matching, there isn't a way to use the queryString to match routes.

What you could do is to create a component that checks the current `location` object's `search` property and conditionally render the appropriate component.

Example:

```
const TestWrapper = (props) => {
  const { search } = useLocation();

  switch (search) {
    case "":
      return <Home {...props} />;

    default:
      return <Test {...props} />;
  }
};
```

...

```
const routes = [
  {
    paths: ["/"],
    component: Home
  },
  {
    paths: ["/test"],
    component: TestWrapper
  }
];
```

Additionally, in `react-router-dom@5` the `Route` component can take an array of paths, so you don't need to explicitly map a route for each path in the `paths` array.

```
const createRoutes = () =>
  routes.map(({ component: Component, paths }) => (
    <Route key={paths.join()} path={paths} exact component={Component} />
  ));
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-differentiate-query-parameters-in-routing-paths-in-react-router]